# Return type of UIImage in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiimage

I have a function which returns image if condition is satisfied else it returns nil

```
- (UIImage *)getProfilePic{
    if (doc.userProperties != nil) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
        return image;
    } 
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

I want to convert this is in swift. I have tried this but it shows error while  returning nil and also it crashes by showing error as unwrapping nil.

```
func getProfilePic(){
    var image : UIImage?
    if doc!.userProperties != nil {
        image = UIImage(named: "placeholder.png")!
        return image!
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

at "return nil" line  it shows nil is not compatible with return type ' uiimage'

Comment: What is the error?  And in which case does it crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code sample :

```
 func getProfilePic() -> UIImage? {
        let imageName = "placeholder.png"
        var image: UIImage?
        if (doc.userProperties != nil) {
            image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        }
        return image
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> func getProfilePic(){
>     var image : UIImage?
>     if doc!.userProperties != nil {
>         image = UIImage(named: "placeholder.png")!
>         return image!
>     }
>     else {
>         return nil
>     }
> }
> ```

Right, so there are a few problems here.  First, your code doesn't have a return type.  If we ignore the body of your method and look just at the signature, the Objective-C equivalent would look like this:

```objc
- (void)getProfilePic;
```

So Swift & Objective-C would be complaining about the same thing here: what you're trying to return and the declared return type of the method do not match.

In case it's helpful since you seem perhaps more familiar with Objective-C than Swift, here's what your Swift method would look like if we translated it back into Objective-C:

```objc
- (void)getProfilePic {
    UIImage *image;
    if (doc.userProperties) {
        image = UIImage(named: @"placeholder.png");
        return image;
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

And again, this would generate the same or similar compile time warnings or errors, because the return type does not match the method signature.  But Objective-C would not crash for unwrapping `nil` (but Swift will).

What you're actually trying to return is a `UIImage?`, so we need to update our method signature.

```swift
func getProfilePic() -> UIImage? {
    if doc?.userProperties != nil {
        return UIImage(named: "placeholder.png")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Assuming that `userProperties` holds perhaps a URL to an image you want to download or maybe the image itself, in the future we're going to want a slightly different construct... something more like this:

```swift
func getProfilePic() -> UIImage? {
    guard let userProperties = doc?.userProperties else {
        return nil
    }

    // extract the image from userProperties and return it
}
```